# Pasar datos de JS a PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Que tal no logro pasar ciertos datos de js a php:

La estructura de algunos **radios buttons**

```
<input class="rad" name="1" id="106" value="0" type="radio">
<input class="rad" name="1" id="45" value="0" type="radio">
<input class="rad" name="2" id="12" value="0" type="radio">
<input class="rad" name="2" id="23" value="0" type="radio">
```

El codigo de **JavaScript**:

```
function guardar(){
  //Declaramos un objeto
 var obj = {};

 //iteramos todo lo que tenga clase rad
 $('.rad').each(function(){

  //Validamos si está chequeado
  if( $(this).is(':checked') ){

    //sacamos el heat en el que se encuentre
    var heat = $(this).attr('name');

    //creamos un nodo con el nombre del heat
     obj[ heat ] = {};

    //Agregamos la información al nodo con el nombre del heat
    obj[ heat ]['id'] = $(this).attr('id');
   // obj[ heat ]['value'] = $(this).val();
  }
 });

 console.log('Esto es lo que se enviará al PHP');
 console.log(obj);

 //abrimos la petición AJAX y no le parseamos ni nada, así pasamos el objeto al nodo "data"
  $.ajax({
    url: 'decode.php',
    method: 'GET',
    data: obj, 
    success:function(response){
      console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(e){
      console.log('Error! El error está en que esta parte no está conectada a tu Back-end');
    }
  })
```

En **PHP**:

```
<?php

var_dump( $_REQUEST );

$heat1_id = $_REQUEST['heat1']['id'];

echo $heat1_id;

?>
```

Realizando una prueba me devuelve lo siguiente:

**Javascript**

[image: front]

**PHP**

```
array(0) { }
```

Muchas gracias a:
@A. Cedano
por la orientacion

y el ultimo codigo que utilice fue de @Alberto Siurob

Comment: Aquí la cuestión importante es tu variable `arrradios2`, la cual no es un json válido. ¿Qué es esa variable, de dónde la sacas, cómo la construyes? *That's the question!*

Comment: Lo construyo apartir de unos radio btn que tengo, donde hago un match de id del radio con el value del mismo, actualizo la pregunta con mas informacion para que puedas verlo

Comment: Listo @A.Cedano

Comment: Ahora se entiende mejor el problema, pero no del todo. Sospecho que estás *mareando*  demasiado el código (dando muchas vueltas para obtener algo que se puede obtener quizá más fácil con otros métodos). Me refiero a todas las vueltas que das para llenar tu `arrradios2`, usando un `for` y dentro de él un operador ternario... al leer el código no termino de entender qué es lo que quieres hacer, quizá si te explicas un poco mejor se te podría proponer una solución más óptima, pero para ello es necesario entender el contexto, el contenido y lo que quieres obtener como resultado final.

Comment: En terminos simples necesito pasar los ids de los radio btn junto con sus values a php.

Comment: Estoy realizando una plataforma de competencias de natacion, dichos radios son parte de los heats (tablas de 3 renglones) para poder marcar al competidor ganador de dicho heat, y pues como es de esperarse tengo generados 280 heats(tablas) con sus respectivos radios, mediante un boton debajo de la tabla mando a llamar al metodo que construi.

Comment: O sea, ¿tú tienes una serie de radio en el HTML y quieres pasarlos todos a PHP como un json donde la clave sea el id de cada uno y el valor sea su estado de `true/false` según esté seleccionado o no? ¿quieres pasar sólo eso o quieres pasar más cosas? Pon un breve ejemplo de cómo tienes los radio en el HTML (si son muchos no hace falta que los pongas todos, sólo dos o tres). JS tiene mejores métodos para hacer lo que quieres, sin tener que *marear* tanto los valores.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77474/discussion-between-jess182-and-a-cedano).

Comment: Listo adjunte una imagen para ver si es mas claro, pero en efecto ya tienes mas o menos la idea de lo que quiero @A. Cedano

Answer (score 1):

La cuestión fundamental está en que recuperes correctamente los radio button y los valores establecidos.

Una forma sencilla de hacerlo sería esta:

### JS / jQuery

```js
$(
  function() {
    $("#frmPersonas").on("submit", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var jsonData = {objeto:"objeto"};
      $("#frmPersonas input[type=checkbox]").each(function() {
        jsonData[this.name] = this.checked;
      });
      
      console.log(jsonData);

/*PETICIÓN AJAX: descomenta este bloque

            $.ajax({
                data: jsonData,  //<--- ***Atención a esto***
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "decode.php",
            })
             .done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
                 if ( console && console.log ) {
                     console.log( "La solicitud se ha completado correctamente." );
                 }
             })
             .fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
                 if ( console && console.log ) {
                     console.log( "La solicitud a fallado: " +  textStatus);
                 }
            });


*/


    });
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Formulario simple que enviará una petición POST -->
<form id="frmPersonas" action="" method="post">
  <label for="POST-name">Nombre  :</label>
  <input id="POST-name" type="text" name="name" value="Prueba" /><br /> Uno:
  <input type="checkbox" name="chkUno" id="chkUno" checked /> <br /> Dos:
  <input type="checkbox" name="chkDos" id="chkDos" /> <br /> Tres:
  <input type="checkbox" name="chkTres" id="chkTres" checked /> <br /> Cuatro:
  <input type="checkbox" name="chkCuatro" id="chkCuatro" /> <br />
  <hr />
  <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

Luego, envías el objeto `jsonData` al servidor mediante Ajax.

Ten en cuenta que aquí tienes un objeto json correcto, al cual puedes agregarle alguna otra clave que quieras para indentificarlo luego en PHP.

Este es un código automático que obtiene el valor de cada radio button, cuando el mismo esté seleccionado, el valor será `true`, mientras que si no lo está el valor será `false`. Puedes aprovechar esa posibilidad, la cual además es más segura que establecer tú mismo valores manuales establecidos a `1` y `0`. Solamente tendrás que tenerlo en cuenta donde vayas a usar los datos, o sea, en vez de verificar si el valor es igual a `1` o a `0`, verificarás si es `true`o `false`.

Creo que todo lo demás es pan comido, pues la gran dificultad de tu código se encontraba aquí, ahora, sólo es cuestión  de pasar `jsonData` al servidor y listo.

### PHP

En el servidor, puedes tratar la petición así:

```
$data= (isset($_GET["objeto"])) ? json_decode($_GET['objeto']) : array ("error"=>"No se posteó la clave objeto");
var_dump($data);
```

Si tienes alguna dificultad me lo comentas.

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda y la explicacion pero sigue sin llegarme nada al back, realmente no entiendo el por que

Comment: @Jess182 propongo que [edites tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/164313/edit), poniendo cómo tienes el código actualmente, así será posible revisarlo. A veces se comenten errores de cambio de nombre de variables, etc. Y comenta cuál es el estado actual, si imprime algo, si no imprime nada, si da error, etc. En mi respuesta yo he asumido que la acción de lanza al hacer clic en un botón, pero tu contexto puede ser otro. El código funcionaría igual, pero puede fallar si el contexto es diferente. Quizá conviene que des más detalles sobre el contexto en la pregunta.

Comment: muchas gracias por la sugerencia en un momento lo edito

Answer (score 0):

Lo que estabas haciendo no estaba mal, sólo que te faltó setear un header y la forma de enviar los datos estaba mal.

#### javascript puro

```
function guardarmarcas(e) {
  var btnid = e.id;
  var arrbtnid = btnid.split("");
  var num = arrbtnid[3];
  var arrradios = document.getElementsByName(num);
  //console.log(arrradios);

  var arrradios2 = {};

  for (var i = 0; i < arrradios.length; i++) {

    arrradios2[arrradios[i].id] = arrradios[i].checked == true ? "1" : "0"
  }


  var jsonradios = JSON.stringify({objeto: arrradios2});
  console.log(jsonradios);

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var response = xhr.responseText;
      console.log(response);
    }
  };
  // url del php
  xhr.open("GET", "decode.php", true);
  // seteo el header como json
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  // envío los datos
  xhr.send(jsonradios);
}
```

#### javascript con jQuery

```
$.ajax({
  data: {objeto: arrradios2},
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "json",
  url: "decode.php",
})
.done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
  if ( console && console.log ) {
    console.log( "La solicitud se ha completado correctamente.");
  }
})
.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
  if ( console && console.log ) {
    console.log( "La solicitud a fallado: " +  textStatus);
  }
});
```

Comment: Agradezco tu respuesta, pero me sigue marcando los mismo errores

Answer (score 0):

Está fácil muchacho.

```js
/*
1. Ponle una misma clase a todos los radios, por ejemplo rad. (Podemos hacer la selección con un selector complejo `$('input[type="radio"]')` pero no se si tengas más selectores de tipo radio en el DOM y esos no los necesitamos.*/
  
   function guardar(){
      //Declaramos un objeto
     var obj = {};
     
     //iteramos todo lo que tenga clase rad
     $('.rad').each(function(){
      
      //Validamos si está chequeado
      if( $(this).is(':checked') ){
      
        //sacamos el heat en el que se encuentre
        var heat = $(this).attr('name');
        
        //creamos un nodo con el nombre del heat
         obj[ heat ] = {};
         
        //Agregamos la información al nodo con el nombre del heat
        obj[ heat ]['id'] = $(this).attr('id');
        obj[ heat ]['value'] = $(this).val();
      }
     });
     
     console.log('Esto es lo que se enviará al PHP');
     console.log(obj);

     //abrimos la petición AJAX y no le parseamos ni nada, así pasamos el objeto al nodo "data"
      $.ajax({
        url: 'decode.php',
        method: 'GET',
        data: obj, 
        success:function(response){
          console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(e){
          console.log('Error! El error está en que esta parte no está conectada a tu Back-end');
        }
      })
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<br>Heat1<br><hr>
<input type="radio" class="rad" name="heat1" value="uno" id="1">
<input type="radio" class="rad" name="heat1" value="dos" id="2">

<br>Heat2<br><hr>
<input type="radio" class="rad" name="heat2" value="tres" id="3">
<input type="radio" class="rad" name="heat2" value="cuatro" id="4">

<br>Heat3<br><hr>
<input type="radio" class="rad" name="heat3" value="cinco" id="5">
<input type="radio" class="rad" name="heat3" value="seis" id="6">

<br>Heat4<br><hr>
<input type="radio" class="rad" name="heat4" value="siete" id="7">
<input type="radio" class="rad" name="heat4" value="ocho" id="8">

<br>Heat5<br><hr>
<input type="radio" class="rad" name="heat5" value="nueve" id="9">
<input type="radio" class="rad" name="heat5" value="diez" id="10">


<br><br><br><input type="button" value="Guardar" onclick="guardar()">
```

**En el PHP**

```
 //Si quieres ver toda la información, $_REQUEST responde a los verbos GET y POST
var_dump( $_REQUEST );

//Para acceder a los nodos y al valor es fácil, por ejemplo
$heat1_val = $_REQUEST['heat1']['value'];
$heat1_id = $_REQUEST['heat1']['id'];
echo $heat1_val;
echo $heat1_id;
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda y muy clara la explicacion, pero sigue sin llegarme nada al lado del servidor

Comment: esto me arroja por el lado del front:

Esto es lo que se enviará al PHP

{…}
​
1: Object { id: "106" }
​
__proto__: Object { … }

array(1) {
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "106"
  }
}
NULL

Comment: Eso es por que los input en name llevan el nombre del heat, por ejemplo heat1 y tu le pusiste un número. Intenta cambiándolo por el heat en donde se encuentren, en tu anterior ejemplo había varios heats, por eso te lo mandé así y el lugar de crearte nodos, te crea un arreglo.

Comment: De igual forma ya estas recibiendo la información en el Back, solo sería de cuestión de iterar y sacar lo que necesitas.

Comment: pero el problema es que no esta llegando la informacion al back